# How to read data from a sqlite table?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have created an application using a sqlite db containing one table with three columns.

```
id     task id   activity id
1      4         12345
2      4         22424
3      5         22424
```

I am getting response from my server in string format

```
tag1=4
tag2=12345
```

How can I search these tag values in my table values?

Comment: Lots of tutorials, once you have a specific question (This is too broad) then ask about a specific problem you're having. Try before asking unless its in terms of design.

Comment: Hi Kiran, please take more time to improve the question next time, also please take a look at your 40 questions and check if you can accept some answers there. I hope my changes still represents what you tried to ask here. If not, edit your question please

Answer (score 2):

get cursor from db and load your list from the cursor, like following query can fetch result matching your criteria:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, 
                null, "id=? AND task_id=?", new String{value1, value2}, null, null);
```